# Feign Retry : No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<feign.Retryer>]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, retry-logic

I am getting the below error while using feign retryer. I am using

io.github.openfeign.feign-core -> v10.10.1

io.github.openfeign.feign-hystrix -> v10.10.1

io.github.openfeign.feign-form -> v3.8.0

**Feign Retryer Error - No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<feign.Retryer>]**

I have the following configuration in my application yml.

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 60000000
        readTimeout: 60000000
      client-service:
        error-decoder: testservice.exception.FeignClientErrorDecoder
        retryer: testservice.exception.FeignClientRetryer
```

Failed to bind properties under 'feign.client.config.client-service.retryer' to java.lang.Class<feign.Retryer>:

```
Property: feign.client.config.client-service.retryer
Value: testservice.exception.FeignClientRetryer
Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:56:18
Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Class<feign.Retryer>]
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Best Regards,
Manuag

Comment: I followed the below article for this: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-customize-feigns-retry-mechanism-b472202be331

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite for your code to run as is:

- `FeignClientRetryer` must be implementing `feign.Retryer`
- `FeignClientRetryer` must have `@Component` stereotype on top of the class.
- `@FeignClient` should have `value="client-service"`

If it still does not run, then You can try this:

1. Remove `@Component` from `FeignClientRetryer`
2. Define a configuration class:

```
public class ClientServiceFeignConfig{

    @Bean
    public Retryer clientServiceRetryer(){
        return new FeignClientRetryer();
    }
}
```

3. And, on top of your `client-service`, add:

```
@FeignClient(value="client-service", configuration = ClientServiceFeignConfig.class)
```